# What's wrong with my reverse() function while?

Tags: javascript, while-loop

My code

When i use word cat the function doesn't return anything.

````
function reverse(str) {
  let result = '';
  let i = str.length-1;
  while ( i < 0) {
    result = result + str[i];
    i--;
  }
  return result;
}// END```
````

Comment: `legth` doesn't exist.

Comment: you have `while (i < 0)`, this must be a typo, as `i` will never be less than 0, and `str[i]` will throw an error if it ever is

Comment: i will indeed be less than 0.  The (i < 0) -- should be (i >= 0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take `length` and the check for greater or equal than zero for the loop.

```js
function reverse(str) {
    let result = '';
    let i = str.length - 1;
    while (i >= 0) {
        result = result + str[i];
        i--;
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(reverse('cat'));
```

A slightly shorter approach with decrementing and check in one.

```js
function reverse(str) {
    let result = '',
        i = str.length;

    while (i--) result = result + str[i];
    return result;
}

console.log(reverse('cat'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `str.length;` instead of `str.legth-1;`
`legth` is not a function. The function in `length`

```js
function reverse(str) {
  let result = '';
  let i = str.length;
  while (i--) {
    result = result + str[i];
  }
  return result;
}
console.log(reverse('ellipsis'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You had a typo and a logic error:

```
function reverse(str) {
  let result = '';
  let i = str.length - 1;  // str.length
  while (i >= 0) { // greater than equal to :)
    result = result + str[i];
    i--;
  }
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use reduce

```js
const reverse = str => str.split('').reduce((result, char) => char + result);

console.log(reverse('cat'));
```